# Codeigniter File Doesn't get Uploaded

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I have the following form and controller where it has a image upload, but everything goes smooth except the file not being uploaded to the particular folder.

View

```
<?php
$this->load->helper('url');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>diluks eCommerce cms - home page</title>
<link href="<?php
echo base_url();
?>Public/scripts/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/addproduct_controller" method="post">
<?php
include 'header-adminpanel.php';
?>
<div class="container">

    <div class="body-content">
        <div class="side-left"><?php
include 'adminproduct_sidebar.php';
?></div>
        <div class="side-right">
        <br />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="captions">Product Code</td>
                <td><input name="txt_pcode" type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="captions">Product Name</td>
                <td><input name="txt_pname" type="text" size="40" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="captions">Product Price</td>
                <td><input name="txt_pprice" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="captions">Product Description</td>
                <td><textarea name="txt_pdesc" style="width:300px;height:100px;"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="captions">Product Image</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="captions">Product Options</td>
                <td><input name="txt_poptions" size="40" type="text" /><a class="hint"> (Separate by a "," comma)</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><input name="btn_add" class="button" type="submit" value="Add" /></td></tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        </div>  
    </div> 

</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Addproduct_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if (isset($_POST["btn_logout"])) {

            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            $this->load->view('welcome_view');
        } else if (isset($_POST["btn_home"])) {

            $this->load->view('welcome_view');

        } else if (isset($_POST["btn_account"])) {


        } else if (isset($_POST["btn_add"])) {

            $prod_img                = 'no image';
            $config['upload_path']   = 'Public/uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']      = '1024';
            $config['max_width']     = '1024';
            $config['max_height']    = '768';
            $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;



            $this->load->library('upload', $config);


            if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {

                //  $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                //$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                //return 'error';

            } else {
                global $prod_img;
                $data     = array(
                    'upload_data' => $this->upload->data()
                );
                $prod_img = $data->file_name;
                //  $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }


            $prod_name    = $_POST["txt_pname"];
            $prod_code    = $_POST["txt_pcode"];
            $prod_price   = $_POST["txt_pprice"];
            $prod_desc    = $_POST["txt_pdesc"];
            $prod_options = $_POST["txt_poptions"];



            $this->load->model('product_model');
            $addproduct_result = $this->product_model->addProduct($prod_code, $prod_name, $prod_price, $prod_desc, $prod_img);

            if ($addproduct_result == true) {

                echo "Added Successfully";

            } else {

                echo "Failed";
            }

        }

    }





}
```

Then I tried by adding following instead of normal  tags.

```
<?php
$this->load->helper('form');
?>


<?php
echo form_open_multipart(base_url().'index.php/addproduct_controller');
?>
```

where it gaves me an error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/addproduct_controller.php

Line Number: 53
```

Please help me with this or show me where I have done the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enctype` attribute missing in your from tag.

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag

**OR**

In CI, Use `form_open_multipart` function to generate form tag

As per discussion in comment, update your code as below.

```
$data     = array(
                    'upload_data' => $this->upload->data()
                );
$prod_img = $data["upload_data"]->file_name;
```

Comment: it gives me an error " Trying to get property of non-object" when I added it like <?php
$this->load->helper('form');
?>


<?php
echo form_open_multipart(base_url().'index.php/addproduct_controller');
?>

Comment: Yes It says "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/addproduct_controller.php

Line Number: 53

Comment: Yes, Now the file is getting uploaded, but still the error comes

Comment: I got it corrected kumar_v, issue was with the line $prod_img = $data->file_name; Thanks alot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out to include form attribute to upload the file

Add enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag

Answer (score 0):

You have make the `html` form but not added file upload tag in your form creation.

add: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag.

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/addproduct_controller" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```